# My Pytorch model is giving very bad results

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I am new with Deep Learning with Pytorch. I am more experienced with Tensorflow, and thus I should say I am not new to Deep Learning itself.

Currently, I am working on a simple ANN classification. There are only 2 classes so quite naturally I am using a Softmax BCELoss combination.

The dataset is like this:

```
shape of X_train (891, 7)
Shape of Y_train (891,)
Shape of x_test (418, 7)
```

I transformed the X_train and others to torch tensors as train_data and so on. The next step is:

```
train_ds = TensorDataset(train_data, train_label)
# Define data loader
batch_size = 32
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

I made the model class like:

```
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
   
        # an affine operation: y = Wx + b
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(7, 32)
        self.bc1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(32)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32, 64)
        self.bc2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 128)
        self.bc3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(128, 32)
        self.bc4 = nn.BatchNorm1d(32)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(32, 10)
        self.bc5 = nn.BatchNorm1d(10)
        self.fc6 = nn.Linear(10, 1)
        self.bc6 = nn.BatchNorm1d(1)
        
        self.drop = nn.Dropout2d(p=0.5)
        
        
    def forward(self, x):
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform(self.fc1.weight)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.bc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        
        x = self.drop(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.bc2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        
        #x = self.drop(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.bc3(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        
        x = self.drop(x)
        x = self.fc4(x)
        x = self.bc4(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        
        #x = self.drop(x)
        x = self.fc5(x)
        x = self.bc5(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        
        x = self.drop(x)
        x = self.fc6(x)
        x = self.bc6(x)        
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        return x
    
model = Net()
```

The loss function and the optimizer are defined:

```
loss = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.00001, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-08, weight_decay=0, amsgrad=False)
```

At last, the task is to run the forward in epochs:

```
num_epochs = 1000
# Repeat for given number of epochs
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        
    # Train with batches of data
    for xb,yb in train_dl:
        pred = model(xb)
        
        yb = torch.unsqueeze(yb, 1)
        
        #print(pred, yb)
        print('grad', model.fc1.weight.grad)
        
        l = loss(pred, yb)
        #print('loss',l)
                    
        # 3. Compute gradients
        l.backward()
            
        # 4. Update parameters using gradients
        optimizer.step()
            
        # 5. Reset the gradients to zero
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    # Print the progress
    if (epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
        print('Epoch [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch+1, num_epochs, l.item()))
```

I can see in the output that after each iteration with all the batches, the hard weights are non-zero, after this zero_grad is applied.

However, the model is pretty bad. I get an F1 score of around 50% only! And the model is bad when I call it to predict the train_dl  itself!!!

I am wondering what the reason is. The grad of weights not zero but not updating properly? The optimizer not optimizing the weights? Or what else?

Can someone please have a look?

I already tried different loss functions and optimizers. I tried with smaller datasets, bigger batches, different hyperparameters.

Thanks! :)

Comment: We don't have your data, so this is not a [mre]. What do you expect us to do? Instead, it would be better for you to review some tutorials on how to debug neural networks.

Comment: Indenting the `optimizer.zero_grad` operation might help. The gradients are now accumulatively affecting the updates i.e. if batch_1 imposes 1 unit and batch_2 imposes 3 unit of gradient update and batch_3 imposes 8 unit of change, optimizer is updating as 1 + (1 + 3) + (1 + 3 + 8) + ... until one epoch ends. By moving that operation under the "batch loop" you will be updating as 1 + 3 + 8 + ... as it is supposed to.

Comment: Also, `torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform(self.fc1.weight)` doesn't really do anything because it is not in-place (functions with underscore at the end are e.g. `torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_`). But weight initialization shouldn't be part of the forward propagation anyway, as it will initialize again and again for each batch.. Best suited for e.g. `__init__` i.e only happening once.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't use softmax activation for BCE loss, unless you have 2 output nodes, which is not the case. In PyTorch, BCE loss doesn't apply any activation function before calculating the loss, unlike the CCE which has a built-in softmax function. So, if you want to use BCE, you have to use sigmoid (or any function f: R -> [0, 1]) at the output layer, which you don't have.

Moreover, you should ideally do `optimizer.zero_grad()` for each batch if you want to do SGD (which is the default). If you don't do that, you will be just doing full-batch gradient descent, which is quite slow and gets stuck in local minima easily.

Comment: But I am already using sigmoid, not softmax. the last line of the forward method of the model class: x = torch.sigmoid(x) .

Comment: what to do regarding the optimizer.zero_grad() can you please explain?

Comment: @KhabbabZakaria ah sorry didn't see that for some reason. Just do the zero grad thing within the loop you iterate over the batches (just one more indentation)